# How to ignore error in VIM key mapping command series?

Tags: vim, keymapping

I'm editing key mappings for line movement as following:

```
vnoremap <silent> <C-j> :m '>+1<CR>gv
vnoremap <silent> <C-k> :m '<-2<CR>gv
```

They are supposed to move the line block up and down and work fine in most cases except at the top and bottom of a file.

When I select the line 1 2, and input ctrl-k, sure, it cannot move anymore upwards, while the expected behavior is that the line 1 2 are still highlight in visual mode.

The current appearance is that, the line 1 2 are not highlight anymore. I know that's because the ":m '<-1" failed, then gv will not be executed.

So my question is how to ignore this error to ensure gv executed anyway? Or some other solutions?

Please note, I know a solution linemovement.vim. It run these in two separated commands and some functions. While I suppose this should be a lightweight code.

Comment: Similar on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/319048/vim-continue-macro-after-error-in-submacro

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need `:silent!` to suppress the output and skip errors:

```
vnoremap <C-j> :<C-u>silent! '<,'>m '>+1<CR>gv
vnoremap <C-k> :<C-u>silent! '<,'>m '<-2<CR>gv
```

- `<C-u>` removes the "selection range" inserted automatically by Vim because `:silent` doesn't accept a range.
- we add `'<,'>` before `:move` so that it still works on the visual selection.

Here is that fix applied to my enhanced (adds autoindenting) version of those mappings:

```
nnoremap ,<Up>   :<C-u>silent! move-2<CR>==
nnoremap ,<Down> :<C-u>silent! move+<CR>==
xnoremap ,<Up>   :<C-u>silent! '<,'>move-2<CR>gv=gv
xnoremap ,<Down> :<C-u>silent! '<,'>move'>+<CR>gv=gv
```

Thanks for the idea.

Comment: This is a solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is an awesome solution. I was trying to do something very similar to this before searching, but I now see what I had done wrong. +1 for the auto-indent. Very nice addition to what I had before.

Comment: Super nice! Thanks a lot!